# MySQL: Update statement shows no errors but changes nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a connection to a database and want to update(override) an existing string called profile by a new one.

```
$uid = 1;
$serProfile = 'abc';

$sql = 'UPDATE
            Users
        SET
            profile = ?
        WHERE
            id = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if (!$stmt) { safeExit($db->error, 'msgError'); }
$stmt->bind_param('si', $serProfile, $uid);
if (!$stmt->execute()) { safeExit($stmt->error, 'msgError'); }
$stmt->close();
```

However, although the variables exist, the fields exist and there are no errors, the values in the database do not get changed. How to resolve this behaviour?

Comment: What about commiting ? or is it configured on auto-commit ?

Comment: I commit it when I refesh the page.

Comment: Should I turn off auto commiting ?

Comment: Check MySQL general log and check what query it's generating

Comment: Well, today this statement worked for me. Maybe a bug in MySQL?

Comment: No, there don't exist any bugs that make MySQL randomly cease to update records one day, and work again the other day. Not as long as your query doesn't contain dates, at least. There are too many questions left open in your question. What happens if you manually write the same update query, does that work? What query gets executed (see query log as @shiplu.mokadd.im suggests)? Drop all error checking, enable all PHP error messages and run the code again, do you see any errors? Is it connected to the right database, and not perhaps another instance? Does the row with ID 1 exist?

Answer (score 0):

Test this one

```
$sql = 'UPDATE Users SET  profile = :profile WHERE id = :id';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('id'=>$uid,'profile'=>$serProfile));
```

Comment: Did not work. Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object on line "$stmt->execute(array('id'=>$uid,'profile'=>$serProfile));
"